# useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress in WCF is not working

Tags: web-services, wcf, web-config, load-balancing, f5

I have WCF service which is deployed on IIS of my local server. The clients will access my service via F5 (load balancer). mean they will call
this url "https://www.something.com:1600/Service/test.svc". now they see WSDL. inside WSDL, my local url (http://servername:13001/Service/test.svc) is shown.
URL should be "https://www.something.com:1600/Service/test.svc". I have tried `

```
<useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress>
       <defaultPorts>
          <add scheme="http" port="81" />
          <add scheme="https" port="444" />
        </defaultPorts>
      </useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress>
```

`
 in my web.config.
but they still can see my local URL. Thanks

Comment: you can use a stream profile to rewrite the payload of http://servername:13001/Service/test.svc to https://www.something.com:1600/Service/test.svc. Details on stream profile can be found here: https://devcentral.f5.com/articles/ltm-stream-profile-multiple-replacements--regular-expressions

Comment: hi @JasonRahm I don't have access to F5. I have tried this link "https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/127248/How-to-replace-Machine-Name-with-Domain-name-in-WC?msg=5542535#xx5542535xx". I am still stuck in this error.

Comment: I don't know the app as well as the F5 capabilities, sorry.